# Erro ao executar Procedure em oracle

Tags: java, query, oracle, pl-sql, procedure

**Tenho essa procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE buscaturma(cod in INTEGER) AS
  nomeT varchar2(20);
BEGIN

  dbms_output.put_line('inicio');

  IF (cod=0)then
    dbms_output.put_line('ZERO');
  ELSE
    SELECT DS_TURMA 
     into nomeT
    FROM TURMA
    WHERE CD_TURMA = cod;
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Não foi possível verificar');

END;
```

**E executo com essa chamada:**

```
EXECUTE  buscaturma(2);
```

**Mensagem de Erro:**

> Erro a partir da linha : 22 no comando - EXECUTE  buscaturma(2)
>   Relatório de erros - ORA-06550: line 1, column 8: PLS-00905: object
>   DBAMV.BUSCATURMA is invalid ORA-06550: line 1, column 8: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: Acho que há alguns ponto-e-vírgulas a mais aí.

Comment: Em qual linha ?

Comment: Conseguir corrigir o erro. porém só recebo a mensagem: bloco anonimo concluido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posso estar enganado mas o que você precisa é de uma função e não de uma procedure, veja se a função abaixo atende a sua necessidade, se mesmo assim quiser retornar um valor utilizando procedure, terá declarar um parâmetro do tipo OUT:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_BUSCARTURMA(P_CODIGO INTEGER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  RESULT TURMA.DS_TURMA%TYPE;
BEGIN

BEGIN
SELECT DS_TURMA 
     INTO RESULT
    FROM TURMA
    WHERE CD_TURMA = P_CODIGO;
    
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL ENCONTRAR A TURMA');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OCORREU ALGUM ERRO AO TENTAR BUSCAR A TURMA');
END;

  RETURN(RESULT);
END F_BUSCARTURMA;
```

Abaixo exemplo de utilização da função:

select F_BUSCARTURMA(1)
from DUAL